# page refuses to load whenever i use the EJS syntax especially when i use 'include'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

The page only loaded once or twice if i'm lucky but refuses to load most times. but whenever i remove the EJS syntaxt from the file and leave just the HTML it loads fine. I cant figure out why this is happening.

```js
This is the file struture

views
   landing.ejs
   campground.ejs
  /partials
      header.ejs
      footer.ejs
```

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); //to use body parser 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.render('landing');
});
//view campgrounds
app.get('/campgrounds', function(req, res) {
 var campgrounds = [
  {name: '', image: ''}
 ]

 res.render('campgrounds', {campgrounds: campgrounds});
});
//post campgrounds
app.post('/campgrounds', function(req, res) {
 //get data from form and add to campground array
 //redirect back to campground page
 res.send('you hit d cmpground post route');
});
//campground form
app.get('/campgrounds/new', function(req, res) {
 res.render('new.ejs');
});



app.listen(port, process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
 console.log(` Yelp camp has started on port ${port}`)
})
```

```html
<% include partials/header %>

<h2>landing Page</h2>
<p>welcome to yelp camp</p>

<a href="/campgrounds">view all campgrounds</a>

 <% include partials/footer %>
```

app.js

Comment: Do you have `ejs` installed ?

Comment: Yes i do @BrahmaDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All i needed to do was to wrap the include footer and header syntax with the header and footer html tag.

```html
<header>
 <% include partials/header %>
</header>


<h2>landing Page</h2>
<p>welcome to yelp camp</p>

<a href="/campgrounds">view all campgrounds</a>

<footer>
 <% include partials/footer %>
</footer>
```